How to integrate Github login with firebase auth in both the web and mobile?
Issue
I created a project in Firebase which consists of 3 apps, the web (NextJS), ios app (React Native Expo), and android (React Native Expo). I added Github as a provider in Firebase Auth and also added a new OAuth app in Github. However, when adding a new OAuth app in Github, I have to provide an Authorization Callback URL which is the problem here. For the web, I have to fill in https://myapp.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler but for the mobile app, I have to fill in myapp:// (myapp is the scheme field in expo's app.json) which is a deeplink to my mobile app. However, I can only provide 1 redirect url. How should I get away with this limitation?
Basically,

The login on mobile works perfectly when I provide myapp:// as the authorization callback URL on Github. But the web would break.
Simiarly, the login on web also works perfectly when I provide https://myapp.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler as the authorization callback URL on Github. But the mobile app would break.
The problem is I can't get both of them to work at the same time.

Github OAuth Setting

Firebase's Github Provider Config

